# How to make a list with vertical aligned text?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make to list with a vertical aligned text, but I couldn't do it no matter how much I tried and searched. So, how do I achieve the following result using twitter bootstrap?!

```
                                   Ahmed: what's your name?
                                   Bob: ahmed
                                   Cate: ok!
```

At the moment I have this, which I can't seem to fix.

```
                              Ahmed: what's your name?
                                   Bob: ahmed
                                    Cate: ok!
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid" align="center">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <ul style="list-style-type: none; vertical-align: middle;">

            <li><h5><strong>Ahmed and his friends</h5></li>
            <li><h5><strong>life is good</h5></li>

        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post your `HTML`?

Comment: probably should remove the text-center class if you have it or the text-align:center in your CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you will need it's to have your ul tag centered on the middle of your page and the li align left

in css you can try to align the item on the right :

```
ul {
  margin-left:35%;
}

li {
    text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: Then it goes to the far left. I don't know why the bullets are not in the middle too

Comment: ok i undertand you need it in the middle of your page but align on the left

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to want to do is have them **left-aligned**, and have that element in the **middle** of the screen.

The easy way to do this is by having 2 elements. The second element is rendered as `inline-block` instead of `block`, so it is not greedy and does not take up all the horizontal space.

```css
#outer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

#inner {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    Ahmed: what's your name?
    <br/>Bob: ahmed
    <br/>Cate: ok!
  </div>
</div>
```